# Data scraping with Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I am able to scrape [http://www.example.com/view-books/0/new-releases](http://www.flipkart.com/view-books/0/new-releases) using Nokogiri but how do I scrape all the pages? This one has five pages, but without knowing the last page how do I proceed?

This is the program that I wrote:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'
require 'csv'

urls=Array['http://www.example.com/view-books/0/new-releases?layout=grid&_pop=flyout',
           'http://www.example.com/view-books/1/bestsellers',
           'http://www.example.com/books/pre-order?query=book&cid=1&layout=list&ref=4b116001-01a6-4f53-8da7-945b74fdb253'
      ]

@titles=Array.new
@prices=Array.new
@descriptions=Array.new
@page=Array.new

urls.each do |url|
  doc=Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
  puts doc.at_css("title").text

  doc.css('.fk-inf-scroll-item').each do |item|
   @prices << item.at_css(".final-price").text
   @titles << item.at_css(".fk-srch-title-text").text
   @descriptions << item.at_css(".fk-item-specs-section").text
   @page << item.at_css(".fk-inf-pageno").text rescue nil
  end

  (0..@prices.length - 1).each do |index|
    puts "title: #{@titles[index]}"
    puts "price: #{@prices[index]}"
    puts "description: #{@descriptions[index]}"
  #  puts "pageno. : #{@page[index]}"
    puts ""
  end
end

CSV.open("result.csv", "wb") do |row|
  row << ["title", "price", "description","pageno"]
  (0..@prices.length - 1).each do |index|
    row << [@titles[index], @prices[index], @descriptions[index],@page[index]]
  end
end
```

As you can see I have hardcoded the URLs. How do you suggest that I scrape the entire books category? I was trying anemone but couldn't get it to work.

Comment: Since the page is not fully loaded on html source, but by some js when user browsing the page. You need something to simulate a user operation or execute the js. It's nothing about nokogiri. Maybe 'watir' gem could help.

Comment: Okay will try it out ...

Comment: It always helps to show the code you've written, so we can help you modify it, rather than expect us to make wild guesses about what you might, or might not, have written.

Comment: The problem with dynamic HTML pages is the JavaScript. Often we have to dig into the source, analyze what they're doing, and then imitate it in our Ruby code to perform the requests. Sometimes you can find hints in the HTML or JavaScript telling you how many pages to expect, and can pull the value out of the script, or a text node. Other times, like this one, you have to loop until you get no results, or you get an error.

Comment: Sorry for the missing code ...I've edited my question ..thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

If you inspect what exactly happens when you load more results, you will realise that they are actually using a JSON to read the info with an offset.

So, you can get the five pages like this :

```
http://www.flipkart.com/view-books/0/new-releases?response-type=json&inf-start=0
http://www.flipkart.com/view-books/0/new-releases?response-type=json&inf-start=20
http://www.flipkart.com/view-books/0/new-releases?response-type=json&inf-start=40
http://www.flipkart.com/view-books/0/new-releases?response-type=json&inf-start=60
http://www.flipkart.com/view-books/0/new-releases?response-type=json&inf-start=80
```

Basically you keep incrementing `inf-start` and get the results until you get the `result-set` less than `20` which should be your last page.

Comment: Wow, they use JSON to deliver HTML snippets--that's kinda ridiculous.

Comment: If you use `response-type=html` they'll return the results as HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an untested sample of code to do what yours is, only written a bit more concisely:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'
require 'csv'

urls = %w[
  http://www.flipkart.com/view-books/0/new-releases?layout=grid&_pop=flyout
  http://www.flipkart.com/view-books/1/bestsellers
  http://www.flipkart.com/books/pre-order?query=book&cid=1&layout=list&ref=4b116001-01a6-4f53-8da7-945b74fdb253
]

CSV.open('result.csv', 'wb') do |row|

  row << ['title', 'price', 'description', 'pageno']

  urls.each do |url|

    doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
    puts doc.at_css('title').text

    doc.css('.fk-inf-scroll-item').each do |item|

      page = {
        titles:       item.at_css('.fk-srch-title-text').text,
        prices:       item.at_css('.final-price').text,
        descriptions: item.at_css('.fk-item-specs-section').text,
        pageno:       item.at_css('.fk-inf-pageno').text rescue nil,
      }

      page.each do |k, v|
        puts '%s: %s' % [k.to_s, v]
      end

      row << page.values
    end
  end
end
```

There are some useful pieces of data you can use to help you figure out how many records you need to retrieve:

```
var config = {container: "#search_results", page_size: 20, counterSelector: ".fk-item-count", totalResults: 88, "startParamName" : "inf-start", "startFrom": 20};
```

To access the values use something like:

```
doc.at('script[type="text/javascript+fk-onload"]').text =~ /page_size: (\d+).+totalResults: (\d+).+"startFrom": (\d+)/
page_size, total_results, start_from = $1, $2, $3
```